# plugin to dynamically generate reports from schema

Tags: c#, .net, reporting, dynamic-reports

I preface this with: this may have been asked before and I can't find it...

Does anyone know of a drag and drop, user control like add-in for a C# .Net web application that allows the user to dynamically build reports off of my SQLServer 2005 database schema?

I'm looking for something user-friendly that I can drop in my web application, with a little configuration, that will let the user generate reports for themselves...

Comment: If you ready to pay some money go for TARGIT :)) http://www.targit.com

Comment: Money is not really a factor, I'm not the one writing the check. :) I'll check it out, do you have a link?

Comment: Do you know about how much this thing costs? Just looking for a rough estimate and you have to actually contact someone to get pricing info... I'm just looking for a ballpark price, why is that so hard to put on a website? :-P